# Camera flash always ON - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am working on a cross platform application that needs to keep the flashlight always ON while the camera is operated. Is there any particular way to do it? 
I tried using the CrossLamp.Current.TurnOn(); but it throws error as the two plugins are not working together.

Comment: What plugin are you using to open your camera ?

Comment: I am using Media plugin